# Refactoring - Checking if promise has been resolved before

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

This function get an user files list provided by an external API. Once that the data has been retrieved it is saved, so the next time it is called it returns the same data previously saved. This code is at controller level.

```
var userFiles = {};

function getUserFiles(user) {
  var dfd = $q.defer();

  // Files already have been loaded
  if (userFiles[user.id]) {
    dfd.resolve(userFiles[user.id]);
  } else {

    // Get files for the first time
    Users.getFiles(user).then(function(files) {
      userFiles[user.id] = files;
      dfd.resolve(userFiles[user.id]);
    });
  }

  return dfd.promise;
}
```

How would you refactor this code so it calls dfd.resolve only once?

Comment: There really isn't anything to refactor here, what you have is correct. Because of the if/else check, you will only hit one of the two `dfd.resolve(...)` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT #2**

I've got an even **better** snippet for you:

```
function getUserFiles(user) {
  return userFiles[user.id] || (userFiles[user.id] = Users.getFiles(user));
}
```

This sets `userFiles[user.id]` to be the promise returned by `Users.getFiles(user)` and returns it. If `userFiles[user.id]` has already been set (i.e. it is truth-y) then it just returns the previously resolved promise.

The disadvatange using this super short snippet is that you aren't doing any failure checking - and could end up caching a failed request - then again, you weren't doing any failure checking in your other code either.

**EDIT**

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), you can call `$q.resolve()` directly without needing to create the intermediate deferred object - i.e. `$q.defer().resolve()`

A minor refactor, the following code saves you from creating a deferred when you don't need to. You only need to create a new deferred if the files have already been loaded. Otherwise, you can just return the call to `Users.getFiles()`, like this:

```
function getUserFiles(user) {

  // Files already have been loaded
  if (userFiles[user.id]) {

//        See Edit Note
//        return $q.defer().resolve(userFiles[user.id]);
        return $q.resolve(userFiles[user.id]);
  }

  // Get files for the first time
  return Users.getFiles(user)
    .then(function(files) {
      //Cache them
      return (userFiles[user.id] = files);
    });

}
```

Comment: I like this one. Nice and clean. It reminds me that I need to stop clinging to my single exit point habit.

Comment: This is actually a really awesome snippet. But as you say, you would be returning promises, right? `userFiles` has to store the list of files.

Comment: @fuxes - It's worth pointing out that that `userFiles[user.id]` will always be a **resolved** promise. So you just have to use the promise interface to access it's list of files, rather than access the files as an array directly - e.g. `userFiles[user.id].then(function(files) { /* do something with files */ });` Or, better yet, whenever you want to access `userFiles` - always access it through the function `getUserFiles` - single source of truth., much easier to maintain the application if you always access the list of files through the same method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userFiles = {};

function getUserFiles(user) {
  var dfd = $q.defer();

  if (!userFiles[user.id]) {
    // Get files for the first time
    Users.getFiles(user).then(function(files) {
      userFiles[user.id] = files;
    });

    dfd.resolve(userFiles[user.id]);
  }

  return dfd.promise;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a risk of calling resolve before `User.getFiles(user)` finishes, and therefore resolving the promise with empty object?

Comment: This will not work since in the case when the data is not in the 'local cache', the promise will be resolved before the data is actually fetched from the remote source.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't consider that the original call to dfd.resolve(userFiles[user.id]); was within the then function().

Comment: Also, if `userFiles[user.id]` is defined it would never resolve the promise